# How to have a carriage return without bringing about a linebreak in VIM?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to have a carriage return without bringing about a linebreak ?
For instance I want to write the following sentences in 2 lines and not 4 (and I do not want to type spaces of course) :

1. On a ship at sea: a tempestuous noise of thunder and lightning heard.
   Enter a Master and a Boatswain
2. Master : Boatswain!
   Boatswain : Here, master: what cheer?

Thanks in advance for your help

Thierry

Comment: You need to have `"Master : Boatswain! Boatswain : Here, master: what cheer?"` on disk and `"Master : Boatswain!\nBoatswain : Here,\nmaster: what cheer?"` on display?

Comment: Are you asking how to configure line wrapping?

Comment: To Jefromi (and ZyX): 
Are you asking how to configure line wrapping? 
No, I did not explain myself clearly enough. My purpose is to be able to write in 1 VIM line considered as a block of text, a dialog distinguishing the protagonists thus :
- Master : (his text) and then have a carriage return bringing to
- Boatswain : (his text at the beginning of the line, just as in a theater play)
And all that piece of dialog in 1 VIM line, then have a new line for instance for didascalia, etc...

You can email me if you wish at : tguillemin@gmail.com

Thierry

Comment: @user413016 I still understand nothing. Write, what you want to be on disk and what on the screen. Or do you need Vim to conceal some parts of the line when you type Enter?

Comment: Or maybe you want getline function, linewise motions (like `d` in `dd`) and other stuff like that use the whole dialogue, while you will see line breaks inside it (and this linebreaks will also be stored on disk).

Answer (score 0):

In a text file, the expected line-end character or character sequence is platform dependent. On Windows, the sequence "carriage return (CR, \r) + line feed (LF, \n)" is used, while Unix systems use newline only (LF \n). Macintoshes traditionally used \r only, but these days on OS X I see them dealing with just about any version. Text editors on any system are often able to support all three versions, and to convert between them.

For VIM, see [this article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_end-of-line_format_for_dos-mac-unix) for tips how to convert/set line end character sequences.

However, I'm not exactly sure what advantage the change would have for you: Whichever sequence or character you use, it is just the marker for the end of the line (so there should be one of these, at the end of the first line and you'd have a 2 line text file in any event). However, if your application expects a certain character, you can either change the application -- many programming languages support some form of "universal" newline -- or change the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is what you're looking for:

```
:set wrap
:set linebreak
```

The first tells vim to wrap long lines, and the second tells it to only break lines at word breaks, instead of in the middle of words when it reaches the window size.